How to restirct google mapi api key for android app built in flutter. Facing error. How to fix?
I am using package of google maps and google place. When I am restricting my maps api key to android apps by the package name and SHA1 key, the maps are not loading and the search for places which uses the auto complete for google places is not working and not showing further suggestions. How to fix??
packages I used with version number:
google_place: ^0.4.3
google_maps_flutter: ^2.0.9
google_maps_webservice: ^0.0.20-nullsafety.2
I have visited some stack overflow solution that is saying to adding headers as x-android-package and SHA1 keys but I am using packages which in background is calling the http methods. so how can I add those?
 defaultTargetPlatform = TargetPlatform.android;
Map<String, String> headers = {};
if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS) {
  // 'x-ios-bundle-identifier': Env().bundleIdentifier,
}

// com.my.app
if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android) {
  // logger.w("Android is Executing********");
  headers = {
    'x-android-package': ENV.package, // com.my.app
    'x-android-cert':
        ENV.SHA1, // signing key used to build/publish the app
  };
}
logger.w("Local headers: $headers");
debugPrint("Local headers: $headers");
logger.w("URL API KEY: ${URLConstants.googleMapApiKey}");
googlePlace = GooglePlace(URLConstants.googleMapApiKey, headers: headers);

This is how I call the places. But after adding restriction there is no search result.
void autoCompleteSearch(String value) async {
var result = await googlePlace!.autocomplete.get(value);
logger.w("Result: ${result?.predictions}");
if (result?.predictions != null && mounted) {
  setState(() {
    predictions = result!.predictions!;
  });
}

}
This is what my function is but The result is coming as empty list after adding restriction.
Still am unable to figure out any processes . If anyone knows how to make it restricted properly do let me know. Because its important for my project.

Edit your post to include the error you see in the logcat.

@MorrisonChang bro I have added the code snippets, so you can look at it and can tell me what is the issue?

What does the logcat show when it does work vs when it doesn't work? Also realize that the google_place library you are using is at 0.4.7 and as a third-party plugin discontinued / not supported by author anymore.

@MorrisonChang I manually has used the api also irrespective of the package . then also am getting a error message like
{error_message: This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address 136.37.99.230, with empty referer, predictions: [], status: REQUEST_DENIED}  this. So what I am missing ???

Google map services comes in three flavors: one that require SHA and uses Google's Java/Kotlin Map SDK in your Android app, the others are for websites either using a server side key OR Google Javascript library. Manually doing a HTTPS request implies either a server side key (static IP addr) or JS library both to my understanding has tricks/auth to prevent spoofing/accurate billing. I would use a server side key only if my workflow fits within the Google TOS regarding caching. I would look to recent third-party Flutter plugins. If none do what you want you will have to call Java/Kotlin code.
